# Accepting args in $emit - Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

A very simple alert implementation using `$emit`, but when passing arguments it behaves as if the event had never even occurred. On the event, I want to set the value of `alert` to the result.

I am listening on mount as:

```
this.$eventHub.$on('alert', data =>       
  this.alert = data
})
```

**Will Work:**

`this.alert` is undefined, but set.

```
this.$eventHub.$emit('alert')
```

**Won't Work:**

`this.alert` is never set & event is never heard.

```
this.$eventHub.$emit('alert', {'message':'Signal Test', 'color':'error'})
```

What is occurring here?

Comment: Are you making use of any package for the eventHub ?

Comment: Can you share how you are creating the `$eventHub` instance?

Comment: See 2nd answer below. It seems it was just because I was trying to test within the same component. Having the signal and listener in separate components fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily an answer, but more a user error. The issue is that I was signalling the event in the same component that I was listening for it on. I used all the same code, just simply moved the listener to a different component.

This may be as designed, but I didn't get any output to make this clear in console so I'm unsure if this behavior is expected or a bug.

Welcome any answers that may offer some context on why this occurs!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this.$emit` from the vue component.
Take this example:

```html
<template>
    <myComponent @customEvent="myCallback($event)" />
</template>
```

And the script:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    myCallback(data) {
      console.log(data); // here you have your event data
    }
  }
}
```

And in your child component:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    onClick() {
      // this.$emit(eventname, data);
      this.$emit('customEvent', 'some data');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How is this different from what I'm doing other than methodology?

Comment: To be honest, I think nothing, I just know that this way works, if this is not what you need you should edit your post to explain why you use this method, and what is the purpose

Comment: The first paragraph does a good job summing it up. This is a simple alerting mechanic where I can pass the message & the type across child components to only need one alert component. In theory, both of these are identical, so I'm not sure it explains what could cause arguments to cause an event to never fire. The argument could be a simple string & it still acts as if it never fired, so your example would do the same. As to why, I'm hoping someone here has run into strange behavior to shed some light.